# AI file looks fine in Illustrator, weird artifacts in Acrobat/InDesign

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, print-design

I was given some *terrible* source files by a client, and after finally finishing the entire job, I'd like to stitch and proof the AI files properly in InDesign. For some reason, even though the AI file looks fine and opens properly in Illustrator, there are these weird dots all over the place when in other software. I suspected that they were from the dotted lines used under the text, but after removing those and bringing it into InDesign, the dots are still present.

Does anybody know what is causing this issue? If so, how can I remove these dots?[image: Why is this happening]

Answer (score 1):

Probably still having some kind of actual dots on the file.

There could be many reasons as to why you're seeing those and we cannot guess the history of these files, which may have been passed between multiple designers and different versions of AI, or resaved between EPS, AI, SVG, PDF. Who knows? These artifacts do show up every now and then when getting vector files from other sources, so that's that i guess.

What you can do is reopen the AI files, go into outline mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> and try to locate and remove these dots/points manually. A manual cleanup is the only option basicly.

If you don't have hundreds of these files, I would personally just remove all text content from the AI files and re-type that via the InDesign document.